# Table test not working on Golang with Receiver Function

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to do some unit testing in Golang. I have this filter structure:

```
tests/
|_ rcv-func.go
|_ rcv-func_test.go
```

My `rcv-func.go` looks like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"


type Player struct {
    health, maxHealth int
    energy, maxEnergy int
    name              string
}

func (p *Player) modifyHealth(newHealth int) {
    p.health = newHealth
}

func (p *Player) modifyEnergy(newEnergy int) {
    p.energy = newEnergy
}

func main() {
    player := Player{
        health:    50,
        maxHealth: 300,
        energy:    20,
        maxEnergy: 100,
        name:      "Jose",
    }
    fmt.Println("Before resting:", player)
    (&player).modifyHealth(150)
    (&player).modifyEnergy(100)
    fmt.Println("After resting:", player)
}
```

And my `rcv-func_test.go` like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

var tests = []struct {
    health int
    energy int
    expect int
    name   string
    goal   bool
}{
    {200, 300, 50, "test1", true},
    {100, 300, 0, "test2", true},
}

func TestModifyEnergy(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tt := range tests {
        (&tt).modifyEnergy(11)

    }
}
```

When I try to test the receiver function `.modifyEnergy()`, the line `(&tt).modifyEnergy(11)` is giving me the following error:

```
(&tt).modifyEnergy undefined (type *struct{health int; energy int; expect int; name string; goal bool} has no field or method modifyEnergy) (exit status 2)
```

What would be the mistake here? It feels it is not defined but the method is clearly defined in the `rcv-func.go` file.

I tried making both receiver functions Public but to no avail.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The method is defined on `*Player` but in your test you are trying to call it on `*<completely different type>`. *What lead you to assume you can call a method on anything other than `*Player`?*

Comment: Note also that, in Go, you will never ever be able to invoke a method on an **unnamed** (or pointer to unnamed) type. Doing `x.M()` where `M` is a method and `x` is of type `struct{ ... }` (unnamed type) is just NOT gonna work. **To declare a method you need a named type, to call the method you need an instance of that named type.**

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva! Understood, but how could I do a table testing while doing that?

Comment: Well it's a bit silly test since all the function's body contains is a single assignment statement but here you go https://go.dev/play/p/HYjfOB1Ik6w.

Comment: @mkopriva when I try to run the tests, it shows: `undefined: Player`. Do I need to create the type Player in the `rcv-func_test.go` file as I did in the `rcv-func.go` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250638/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-josegp).